# How do you capture Data Changes in Amazon RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am looking to capture data changes that happen on my RDS. How can I do this?

RDS Events looks promising for configuration changes but doesn't seem to support capturing data changes.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Events.html

Comment: You can try RDS snapshot and compare it with the last one. It will show you the data changes within the specific time.

Comment: Which database engine are you using? What will you be doing with the change information?

Comment: End to end monitoring of customer action all the way to DB level.